# Render js file compiled by jade by nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

I have some issue with rendering js file that my gulp-jade compiled.
Here how it looks like:
Gulpfile.js is creating index.js:

```
gulp.task('templates', function () {
gulp.src('./views/*.jade')

    .pipe(wiredep({
        directory: './bower_components',
        //   bowerJson: require('./bower.json'),
        ignorePath: '/dist'
    })).pipe(jade({
  client: true
}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./views'))
    .pipe(livereload());
```

});

And it generate index.js that looks like this:

```
function template(locals) {
var buf = [];
var jade_mixins = {};
var jade_interp;

buf.push("<!DOCTYPE html5><html><head><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\"/><title>Simple online game</title></head><body><!-- bower:js--><script src=\"../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js\"></script><!-- endbower--><h1>Co jest?</h1></body></html>");;return buf.join("");
}
```

And now my problem is to render that views/index.js file by node server. I have gulp task that run server like this:

```
gulp.task('server', function () {
server.listen({ path: './server.js' });
```

});

And my server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var jade = require('jade');
var app = express();

app.set('views', './views');

app.set('view engine', 'js');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var html = jade.renderFile('index');
  res.render(html);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server is running');
});
```

And when I run gulp task I get error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'index'
>      at Error (native)
>      at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
>      at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)

And I change path to this:

```
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var html = jade.renderFile('./views/index.js');
  res.render(html);
});
```

I get error like this:

> Error: ./views/index.js:6
>      4| var jade_interp;
>      5| 
>   6| buf.push("Simple online game
>
> ## Heade
>
> ");;return buf.join("");
>      7| }
>
> Unexpected character s expected , `\n`, `,`, `!` or `=`

What am I doing wrong? How to set up server right?

Comment: You don't need to compile anything in order to use jade file in express app. Simply setup express to use jade view engine and run your app. The jade files will be compiled to html for you.

Comment: Problem is that I want to compile index for bower_components and when I set up server like this:
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

Jade get index without added script by wiredep...

Comment: Finally get through it. I just delete app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  var html = jade.renderFile('index');
  res.render(html);
});
Application know what to do when I set  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.static('public'));